# drop shadow on bootstrap carousel dots

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to have a shadow under Bootstrap 3 default Carousel navigation dots. I thought it would had been a simple task, as setting a box-shadow property for the *ol* that generates the dots, instead I'm unable to achieve the result. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Share the code you've tried

Comment: can you please provide a jsfidle with what u've tried already ?

Comment: I had tried adding shadows as:

.carousel-indicators li {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

also tried text-shadow, and the !important option (which I usually try to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
.carousel-indicators li,.carousel-indicators .active{border: 1px solid black}
```

Comment: Done. First of all, thank you for reply. What I have now is: black rings, with black ring filled white for the active one. This is not what I wanted to achieve (white rings (and full filled dot for active one) with a shadow), but at least they're now somewhat visible on both light and dark images. So this is already an improvement form where I was. Thank you.

Comment: Update: adding "box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666;" to your rule, DO generate proper shadow! Thank you.

I'm almost set. It could be great having shadow visible inside the empty dots (inactive ones) but as is it's almost perfect, thank you very much. Obviously, I was putting my css in the wrong place. Thank you.